# Changing the PATH from perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, path, environment-variables

So I need to call some perl scripts from another script. To make it work from the terminal I need to go to bash and then change the PATH:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/lsk250/www/portfolio
```

Now I need to run this as a CGI and invoke it from a browser, but obviously when I try to invoke the script from the browser, the PATH is not set so the script can't find the programs needed. How can I change the PATH from inside a perl script?
I tried the following, without success:

```
system "export PATH=\$PATH:/home/lsk250/www/portfolio";
```

and

```
$ENV{PATH} = '/home/lsk250/www/portfolio';
exec 'env',cwd().'/'.$0,@ARGV;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "PATH is not set so the script can't find the programs needed." is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ENV{PATH} = "$ENV{PATH}:/home/lsk250/www/portfolio";
```

is indeed correct. It's Perl's equivalent to `sh`'s

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/lsk250/www/portfolio"
```

Contrary to what you said, the subsequent `exec` will use this path to locate the executable, and that executable will see the updated PATH.

You seem to have misdiagnosed the problem. What is actually happpening? Is the `exec` failing? If so, what error did it return?

Comment: The perl script in the question set `$PATH` to just the one directory, that likely would not contain `env` so the exec would fail.

Comment: Changing my ENV line to yours fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions :

```
my $myPath = "/foo/bar";
exec("PATH=$PATH:$myPath command");
```

or

```
my $myPath = "/foo/bar";
exec("$myPath/command");
```